# Не подсвечивается синтаксис (Методы) в Pycharm в теле with as

Tags: python, sqlite, pycharm

[image: скриншот]

Добрый день господа. Столкнулся в тем что не работают подсказка/подсветка методов. На скриншоте видно что if not / values не подсвечивается, а  .cursor .execute  .commit никак не вылазит подсказка(которая ускоряет написание кода) . Хотя метод .connect предлагается для выбора по TAB.

Не могу понять это где то настраивается или модуль sqlite3 криво установился?
возможно что то не так в коде? только начал изучать python

Answer (score -1):

File -> setting -> editor -> color scheme

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]